# Data Logger PIC16F877A

Tags: c, microcontroller, pic, mikroc

I have to design a Data Logger programusing mikroC PRO to run on the EasyPIC5 board (with PIC 16F877A microcontroller). I also have to use a 2-line LCD for display.

Here is what i have been given:

The program will take measurements from Analogue Port AN0 at regular intervals, and save the raw data to
EEPROM. The user should be able to select any of 6 memory banks to store the results of a logging session,
and should be able to set the time interval between readings at 1 second, 2 seconds, 5 seconds or 10
seconds. The number of readings taken in each logging session should be set to 5, but should be alterable from a #define in the first few lines of the program. Another #define should be used to specify the total number of memory banks (set to 6).

Having quite a bit of trouble with this.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

Up till now i am able to get the readings of AN0 and i write them to EEPROM.. BUT the my question which i stupidly missed to ask.. how would i set the the memory banks to 6 and how to save the logging session to any of the banks

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @ouah sorry i forgot to ask the question, i edited my question..sorry again..

Comment: @Pradheep i edited the question.. and added what part i reached.. thanks

Comment: consult your data sheet on what fuse bit to set. For writing EEPROM check your compiler user guide. I am sure you will find examples if you google . The best forum to ask micro chip related question is micro chip  foru

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i = 0; i < k; i++)             // Fill data buffer
EEPROM_Write(0x00+i, i);           // Write data to address 0x00
```

By changing the initial value of `i` and `k` you can determine where to store your data.